# How to get distance from one origin to multiple destination (Direct distance) with HERE MAP REST API

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm using the matrix calculation, but it gives me real driving distance. I'm wondering is there another REST api can calculate distance from one origin to multiple distance? I don't need real driving distance, just approximate distance is fine for my app. Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would you be able to elaborate on your use case?

Comment: @PersistentPlants I'm creating a web app that sort out product by the distance between the client and seller. So I'm using this api to get the distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula) that helps you calculate distances for latitudes and longitudes, you can use HERE Geocoding API to get lat/long for an address and without making a call, calculate this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for that, because you can simply calculate the distances by yourself. Just google "distance between two points" to find out the formula.

Comment: I never thought about this, since I started to use the API for providing address autocomplete.